# Embedding a Voice in application, Android

Tags: android

This is my code's body, I want to embed the voice using      TextToSpeech to read "Color is RED" and I don't know where and how to put it
It always having problem by defining the variable for the String and TextToSpeech.
Any help?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);

     targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

     buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }});
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
 Uri targetUri = data.getData();
 Bitmap bitmap;
 try {
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
  targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}

final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
final TextView textViewCol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewColor);
final TextView textViewVal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);

targetImage.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener(){     


    TextToSpeech mTts ;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
        textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +       
        String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());

        textViewVal.setText("[" + Color.red(pixel) + "," + Color.green(pixel) + ","     + Color.blue(pixel) + "]");

        if ((Color.red(pixel) > 200) && (Color.blue(pixel) < 10) &&     (Color.green(pixel) < 10)) {
               textViewCol.setText("Color is Red.");       
            }
return true;    }     
});

}

protected int valueOf(float x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the article here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

But to do some simple text to speech, use code a bit like this:

```
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
private ImageView targetImage;

private TextView textView;
private TextView textViewCol;
private TextView textViewVal;
private boolean hasTTSBeenInitialized = false;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadimage);

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textViewCol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewColor);
targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.targetimage);
textViewVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);

buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});

//Initialise tts here so you can use it at anytime in the activity.
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
    hasTTSBeenInitialized = true;
    }
  });

  mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);   
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri targetUri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
    targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

targetImage.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

}

OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView) v);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

    textViewVal.setText("[" + Color.red(pixel) + "," + Color.green(pixel) + "," + Color.blue(pixel) + "]");

    if ((Color.red(pixel) > 200) && (Color.blue(pixel) < 10) && (Color.green(pixel) < 10)) {
    //only attempt to play if tts has been initialised, if it hasnt then play it later when it has been initialised
    if(hasTTSBeenInitialized){
        mTts.speak("Color is Red", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }else{
        //Maybe add it to a queue to play when it has been initialized
    }
    textViewCol.setText("Color is Red.");
    }
    return true;
}
};
```

Comment: thanX for the link, that was somehow useful, but check this out. i updated my question, can u tell me where the problem is?!

Comment: I have updated my answer... you didn't not explain what problem you are having, but I have just ran the code I have suggested and it works :)

Comment: I know that it works in this way, and I'm grateful for your early reply, but let me explain the problem now:
My sentence is already inside an      OnTouchListener, and I don't know where to implement it.
I update my question again, now you can see where my problem is ... how to embed this code there?!

Comment: Ok, so you are fine with the text to speech bit? but you need to know how to get the colour of the pixel that was clicked?

Comment: well, if u see the code, that is there in this line: 
textViewVal.setText("[" + Color.red(pixel) + "," + Color.green(pixel) + ","     + Color.blue(pixel) + "]");
but my question is, how to put the code for TextToSpeech inside this line (if):
if ((Color.red(pixel) > 200) && (Color.blue(pixel) < 10) &&     (Color.green(pixel) < 10)) {
               textViewCol.setText("Color is Red.");       
            }

Comment: I have updated my code again, hopefully you should be able to copy and paste that, however I cant test as I do not have the activity result code from the other activity, where you are getting the image from.

Comment: Thanx Man, it worked Properly, although i made some few changes but, still, I appreciate what u did.
now that everything is working good, I'm having this problem with the pixels ... I mean the application works only on pictures which are having only solid colours, but for a normal photo which is taken, it doesn't always take the pixel value of where user selects it. for testing it, I took a colorful pic with my phone, and it was just taking the color of background, where do u think the problem is?!

Comment: I noticed I had some trouble, as the co-ordinates you receive is from the top left of the screen, not from the top left of the ImageView, so you will have to look into how to get the correct pixel.  Afraid I am not sure how to do that.